# an example of discrete factor group of exponential growth

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I would like to understand if there is a discrete infinite group of exponential growth/intermediate growth such that its group von Neumann algebra is a $II_1$ factor. I would be happy to get an explicit example if such group exists. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, any ICC group (with your growth requirement) by Murray and von Neumann. You have a lot of choice...

Comment: @YCor: since this is the kind of thing which is easy for those who know it and not so easy for those who don't, why not leave your comment as an answer, so that the question is not left open as "unanswered"?

Comment: The unique closing vote is as "unclear". The question is perfectly clear.

Comment: (But indeed the title is misleading)

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your comments and answers. Would anyone suggest a better title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(For non-specialists: $G$ is embedded into $\mathcal{B}(\ell^2_{\mathbf{C}}(G))$ as unitaries induced by left translations, and its von Neumann algebra $LG$ is its bicommutant. To say that $LG$ is a factor means that the center of $LG$ is reduced to scalars.)

By a classical result of Murray and von Neumann, the von Neumann algebra of a group $G$ is a factor (and then $II_1$-factor) iff the group is ICC, that is, $\mathrm{FC}(G)=1$, where $\mathrm{FC}(G)$ is the union of finite conjugacy classes of $G$. Equivalently this means that $G$ has trivial center and trivial finite radical, i.e., has no nontrivial finite normal subgroup. (That this condition is necessary is trivial.)

If $G\neq 1$ is finitely generated and ICC, then $G$ is not virtually nilpotent. Among other groups, there are plenty of ICC groups: non-abelian free groups, etc, and also many elementary amenable ones too (e.g. polycyclic). In intermediate growth there are plenty of examples too (just-infinite groups such as Grigorchuk groups...).

Actually, any non-virtually-nilpotent finitely generated group has a nontrivial ICC quotient.

Comment: minute correction: "(and then $II_1$-factor)" should be "(and then $II_1$-factor if $G\neq 1$)"...